# How to return multiple JTextField using JComponent?

Tags: java

I'm trying to return multiple `JTextField` using getter method but I still don't have idea have can I return them as bulk. I know how to return single `JTextField` using this.

```
public JTextField getJTextField()
{
   return this.tfLastName;
}
```

But I wanted to return multiple `JTextField` so I passed to a parameter the `JComponent` I'm little bit stack here in this part.

```
public JTextField getJTextField(JComponent input)
{
}
```

By the way I'm using GUI builder. Any tips or help would appreciated!

Comment: tfLastName is a single textfiled in your class. Have you declared an array of textfield as well ?

Comment: What do you mean by `using JComponent` ? What is the `JTextField` expected ? You can just use a getter returning an Array. Just need to know which Components you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<JTextField> getAllJTextField(JComponent input) {
    List<JTextField> list = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    for (Component c : input.getComponents()) {
        if (c.getClass().equals(JTextField.class)) {
            list.add((JTextField)c);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

or if you want more universal method:

```
public static <T extends Component> List<T> getAllJTextField(JComponent input, T clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Component c : input.getComponents()) {
        if (c.getClass().equals(clazz)) {
            list.add((T)c);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This is better than the OP's answer, as it is project-agnostic, and can be made into a `public static` utility function. +1

Comment: Just need to improve that for `JPasswordField` or other subclasses of `JTextField`, but this is the way to do it.

Comment: @thomas.adamjak I was think more about `JTextField.class.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass())` to check if JTextField is the same or a super class ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to insert multiple `JTextField`:

```
public JTextField[] getJTextField()
{
   JTextField[] textField = new JTextField[3];
   textField[0] = tfLastName;
   textField[1] = tfFirstName;
   textField[2] = tfMiddleName;
   textField[3] = tfNickname;

   return textField;
}
```

Comment: Just need to return the TextField Array an your getter is ok.

Comment: Francis, I'm afraid this might be poor design for what you probably want to achieve. I don't see many situations where you'd need to return a `List` or `Array` of components in Swing in the way you're using them. It seems to be this might be a turn away from proper MVC (Model-View-Controller) design, which is what Swing was designed for (doubly true for NetBeans', and most other GUI builders). Can you please edit the question to include more info about what your problem is related to? Or in other words, what you're trying to achieve, that needs returning multiple TextFields?